# including authorization header jsonp using plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsonp

How do I send authorization headers with this jsonp request using plain javascript? Do I need to put it in the url? I'm trying to use jsonp to fetch twitter api which requires authorization info to be included.

Comment: It isn't possible to add request headers with JSON-P.  Also... don't use JSON-P.  It isn't necessary anymore.  You're opening up yourself to unreliability and potential security issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what you say, just put the authorization as a parameter behind the link, like:

```
http://twitters?token=xxxxx
```